# How to implement a Search Algorithm

Tags: php, database, search, search-engine

This is the first time I am writing an actual search feature for my database.

The database consists of hotel names, hotel food items, hotel locations.

I would like the above three to show up during a search of a string.

Are there any common search algorithm or packages that can be used ?

EXPECTED RESULT SET:

## id | name | description | table_name | rank

56 | KFC| Fried chicken | hotel | 1

12 | [food item name] | [food item description] | food_item | 2

19 | [hotel name] | [hotel description] | hotel | 3

....

Comment: depends how complex you want to get, and what database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean a relational database?  If yes, your "search" algorithm is a WHERE clause.

Do you mean contextual search?  Lucene is a great search engine implementation written in Java.  This might help you marry it with Lucene:

http://www.cabotsolutions.com/2009/05/using-solr-lucene-for-full-text-search-with-mysql-db/

The answer is far more complicated if you're thinking about crawling web sites based on some criteria.  Please clarify.

Comment: I've not seen a better answer today. +1

Comment: No I do not mean the "where" clause. I would like my search results to be ranked depending on the search string. Not the simple select * from ...

Comment: I have three different tables to search, and I do not want to write three different queries and then compile my search.

Comment: @Prakash You should provide an example result-set for your search algorithm if this answer isn't what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Microsoft SQL Server, FreeText works very well:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx

Comment: thank you, I am looking into how to enable full text search for my mysql database.

Comment: The answer mentions "Free Text", which only exists in Microsoft SQL Server.  Try the above link for fulltext search with MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider you're using mysql.

Well your question is basically: how to write a query that will search hotel name, food items, and hotel location.

I guess theses 3 informations are stored in 3 different tables. The easiest way would be to simply query the 3 tables one after the other with query like theses:

```
SELECT * FROM hotel WHERE hotel_name LIKE "%foobar%";
SELECT * FROM hotel_food_item WHERE item_name LIKE "%foobar%";
SELECT * FROM hotel_location WHERE hotel_name LIKE "%foobar%" OR street_name LIKE "%foobar%" OR city LIKE "%foobar%";
```

- Make sure your search term are safe from SQL injection
- You may (or not) want to group the query into 1 bigger query

If your database is becoming large ( like < 100 000 line per table ), or if you have a lot or search query, you might be interested in creating **a search index**, or use **a dedicated database** intend for text search, like elastic search or something else.

Edit: 
If relevance is a matter, use `MATCH AGAINST`:

- http://maisonbisson.com/blog/post/10752/making-mysql-do-relevance-ranked-full-text-searches/
- http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Using-Relevance-Rankings-for-Full-Text-and-Boolean-Searches-with-MySQL/
- [PHP MySQL Search And Order By Relevancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344199/php-mysql-search-and-order-by-relevancy)

You'll have to create 3 subqueries that do `MATCH AGAINST`, and them compile them together. You can do `AGAINST("foobar") as rank` so you'll have the score you needed.

This should look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT id, 'hotel' as table_name, MATCH (search_field1) AGAINST ("lorem") as rank FROM tableA
UNION 
SELECT id, 'food' as table_name, MATCH (search_field2) AGAINST ("lorem") as rank FROM tableB
) as res

ORDER BY res.rank DESC
```

Comment: :) I know I could do that. 
But I want to be able to rank my results depending on the search key.

Comment: @Prakash Raman Edited answer for detail about relevance search.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. Looking into that now. Also, I have added more detail to my question, to make it sound a little less stupid !

Comment: The hard part of your question is to fill the table_name field of the result you expect. Each subquery (see my edit) should return a static value in his select that is the table name.

Answer (score 1):

if you are not using innodb table, and instead are using myisam, you can use mysql's built in full text search.

this works by first putting a full-text index on the columns you wish to search, and then creating a query that looks roughly like this:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(column_to_search) AGAINST($search_string) AS relevance
FROM your_table
WHERE MATCH(keywords) AGAINST($search_string IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY relevance
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: not quite as advanced as the also suggested lucene, but easier to implement, and from what I've experienced, works quite well.